# How can i attach image file to my app mail in iOS

Tags: ios7

I have an app. On a click on the button I want the screen of the app should be captured and MailComposer window should be opened and the image captured previously should get attached to it. The mail sent but there is no attached image file

plz help me.
thank in advance...,

My code is here....

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller =[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"Screen shot maker"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"Hi , <br/> This is Screen Shot Maker" isHTML:YES];
[controller addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"myScreenShot.png"] mimeType:@"png" fileName:@"myScreenShot.png"];

if (controller)
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
//    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/image" fileName:@"Test.png"];

if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
}
else
{
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
}
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir.., it works for me...!!! you saved my time, once again thank you.

Comment: @user3156787 You didn't accept my answer. And also can you vote up?

Comment: @user3156787 click on checkmark button below my answer vote up arrow's.

Comment: Sir.., I'm new to stack over flow , so that require 15 reputation for vote up, After i got 15 reputation surely ill vote you . ThankYou.

Comment: @user3156787 i got you but you can accept my answer for that don't require 15 reputation.